# std::deque memory-address as array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-address, deque

I know that it is legal to "convert" a vector to a c-style Array using the following method:

```
std:vector<char> v;
char *c = &v[0];
```

Is the same also true for a std::deque?

Comment: No. Unlike `std::vector`, `std::deque` could use more than one segment of contiguous memory. You could think of it as *container of small arrays* and the arrays actually contain the elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. In general, the contents of a `std::deque` are not stored contiguously:

> As opposed to std::vector, the elements of a deque are not stored contiguously: typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque).